# how add class active in li when li clicked in dynamic navigation?

Tags: php, html

a want to add class active in `li` side in my navigation
html code

```
<ul class="sidenav" id="sidemenu">
    <li><a href="index.php?page=home"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home ikonKanan"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file ikonKanan"></i>Data<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down ikonKiri"></i></a>
            <ul id="demo" class="collapse warna">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Data Barang</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?page=supplier">Data Supplier</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

php code to select page

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page=$_GET['page'];

    switch ($page) {
        case 'home':
            include('php/select.php');
            break;
        case 'supplier':
            include('php/selectsupplier.php');
            break;

        default:
            echo"<center><h3>Halaman tidak ditemukan!!!</h3></center>";
            break;
    }
}else{
    include('php/select.php');
}

?>
```

and css

```
.active {
background-color:red;
}
```

how i can add class in `li` to change `background-color` of `li` in current page after i clicked `li` navigation.

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

**Using Jquery**

```
$('#sidemenu li').click(function(){ $(this).parent().find('li.text_color').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); });
```

Comment: not work, this is my css active class <code>.sidenav li.active a{
 background-color:#e6e6e6;
 color:#4c4c4c;
}</code>, when i put manually it work great, but when i use jquery it not work

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a scripting language that executes and is finished as soon as the page is loaded. While it is good for dynamically displaying content, it will not change any existing material once it is on the page. For that you need Javascript.

You can do it in plain javascript, or with a library like jQuery to make things much easier.

```
// load jquery from a CDN
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  ></script>

// script to change the classes on click

<script>
$("#sidemenu li").click(function() {
    //first remove the existing element with active class, if it exists.
    $("#sidemenu li .active").removeClass("active");

    //then add active to the clicked item
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
</script>
```

Comment: not work, this is my css active class <code>.sidenav li.active a{ background-color:#e6e6e6; color:#4c4c4c; }</code>, when i put manually it work great, but when i use jquery it not work